# Ionic apps how to update automatically on playstore?

Tags: ionic-framework

I have a app on playstore. I uploaded new version which is showing also new update on playstore. But i want to update automatically without clicking update button. Many apps like facebook etc publish update and in our mobile it will automatically update without asking. i want same like this it will update automatically on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

for Android you can use the following plugin of ionic to [auto update](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/app-update/)

and for iOS I think theres an option for autoupdate and it works if the phone is not on `Low battery mode`.

Answer (score 0):

> For Ionic you can use [Codepush](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/code-push)  "A cloud service that enables
>   Cordova and React Native developers to deploy mobile app updates
>   directly to their users’ devices."
>   https://github.com/microsoft/code-push